# CF10 Remove websocket sub-channels

Tags: coldfusion, websocket, coldfusion-10

Have a requirement to remove an obsolete sub-channel from the main channel without removing others.  I've tried `ArrayDelete(WSGetAllChannels(ChannelName), obsoleteSubChannel)`  assuming 
that the array produced represents an object array of sub-channels but it appears to be just a text presentation.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: What is a sub-channel? Do you have any documentation on it?

Comment: FYI have a look at https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Using+WebSocket+to+broadcast+messages


  [1]: https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Using+WebSocket+to+broadcast+messages

Comment: A channel is like a topic which is nothing more than a logical separation of message types. IMO there isn't a way to unregister a channel once created (You may want to log a bug with adobe). However the client may choose to unsubscribe any channel at any point of time. Why do you want to unregister?